# SQL Server : update multiple rows one by one while incrementing id

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am pretty new to SQL and I thought I was comfortable using it after a while but it still is tough. I am trying to increment ids. I know I could use auto-increment but in this case there are id has relationship with several categories so it has to start with different numbers so I can't do it.

The table looks something like this:

```
id     category
----------------
1000   1
1000   1
...
2000   2
2000   2
...
```

And I want to make it:

```
id     category
------------------
1000   1
1001   1
1002   1
...
2000   2
2001   2
...
```

I tried:

```
UPDATE T1
SET id = CASE 
             WHEN EXISTS (SELECT id FROM STYLE WHERE T1.id = id)
                THEN (SELECT MAX(CAST(id AS INT)) + 1  
                      FROM STYLE 
                      WHERE category = T1.category) 
         END
FROM STYLE T1 
WHERE idStyle = idStyle
```

But it just added 1 to all rows. How could I go 1 by 1 so it could actually get the incremented max id? Thank you.

Comment: You can use a cursor to iterate your table. Here is a link to the MSDN documentation on declaring a cursor,  and using it to iterate a table (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Add a separate column for your custom_id and category and maintain it yourself.  Index it for speed of searching. Leave the database to look after the auto-increment ids.Trying to fight the database over who maintains table relationship ids will end in tears. ;-/

Comment: A `CURSOR` would be an awful way to do this. It could be incredibly slow.

Comment: So, what if you have more than 1000 values for `Category` for any 1 `Id`?

Comment: @Larnu True, I was just answering his question about "How could I go 1 by 1 so it could actually get the incremented max id"

Comment: Start by asking yourself a question:  "What does the existing Id column actually represent?"  It isn't really an Id if you have it being duplicated.  Maybe you need to add an auto increment identity, change "Id" to a more meaningful name, and then apply any relevant foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absense of real sample data, this is a pseudo-sql, however, something like...

```
UPDATE YT
----SELECT NULL as Ihave no context of other fields in your table
SET id = id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1
FROM YourTable YT;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `row_number()` function instead :

```
select *, 
       concat(cid, row_number() over (partition by id order by category)-1) as NewId
from style s;
```